# Changing the language by I18n on ruby on rails - leads to the fact that the language sometimes changes by itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim, rails-i18n

I made a language change and it works, but sometimes after several page updates, the language changes to another, then back - please help, I don't know what to do here

Method for lang change:

```
def switch_locale
  locale = params[:format].to_sym
  I18n.locale = locale

  redirect_to request.referrer
end
```

buttons for lang change:

```
    .min-h-screen.flex.flex-col.items-center.justify-start.fixed.top-0.left-0.w-full.pb-12.pt-32
      = button_to("rus", switch_locale_path('ru'), class: "btn font-bold btn-main rounded-lg fixed top-0", style: "right: 0.25rem")
      = button_to("en", switch_locale_path('en'), class: "btn  font-bold btn-main rounded-lg fixed top-0", style: "right: 4rem")
```

Comment: `I18n.locale = <...>` is _not_ robust - it can leak into subsequent queries under certain circumstances. And it seems that now you _rely_ on this unintentional leak - as far as I understand you _expect_ that the locale will be kept for the redirect request as well (which is not necessarily true). Check the `I18n` [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests)  - the recommended way of handling locales is explicit wrapping the controller's action into `I18n.with_locale`...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov thanks, you are correct. Problem was solved after creating routes for en and ru locales + some stuff from documentation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put locale in cookies so it can be persisted in user's browser (more about it [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html)).
Adding  `|| root_path` is important, as user can access `switch_locale` directly in their browser's address bar, so user will not have error when they do that.

```
def switch_locale
  cookies[:locale] = params[:format].to_sym

  redirect_to request.referrer || root_path
end
```

then use `before_action` on `ApplicationController` to set locale from cookies, so user will have same experience when access any page after switch language, and if cookies does not exist we can use default locale (you can replace `:en` with `I18n.default_locale` if you want to use default from `I18n` config)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale
  
  private
  
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = cookies[:locale] || :en
  end
end
```